# Connect to Azure ML Workspace with Python SDK1 in Compute Instance

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service

I have a script that allow me to connect to Azure ML Workspace. But it only works in local (interactive authentification) or on Cluster Instances while doing experiences.

But I can not manage to make it work in Compute Instances.

```
from azureml.core import Workspace
from azureml.core.run import Run, _OfflineRun

run = Run.get_context()

if isinstance(run, _OfflineRun):
    workspace = Workspace(
        "subscription_id",
        "resource_group",
        "workspace_name",
    )
else:
    workspace = run.experiment.workspace
```

I tried to use https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azureml-core/azureml.core.authentication.msiauthentication?view=azure-ml-py but it did not work.

```
from azureml.core.authentication import MsiAuthentication
from azureml.core import Workspace

msi_auth = MsiAuthentication()
workspace = Workspace(
            "subscription_id",
            "resource_group",
            "workspace_name",
            auth=msi_auth,
        )
```

> File ~/localfiles/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/azureml/_vendor/azure_cli_core/auth/adal_authentication.py:65, in MSIAuthenticationWrapper.set_token(self)
> 63 from azureml._vendor.azure_cli_core.azclierror import AzureConnectionError, AzureResponseError
> 64 try:
> ---> 65     super(MSIAuthenticationWrapper, self).set_token()
> 66 except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError as err:
> 67     logger.debug('throw requests.exceptions.ConnectionError when doing MSIAuthentication: \n%s',
> 68                  traceback.format_exc())
> File ~/localfiles/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/msrestazure/azure_active_directory.py:596, in MSIAuthentication.set_token(self)
> 594 def set_token(self):
> 595     if _is_app_service():
> --> 596         self.scheme, _, self.token = get_msi_token_webapp(self.resource, self.msi_conf)
> 597     elif "MSI_ENDPOINT" in os.environ:
> 598         self.scheme, _, self.token = get_msi_token(self.resource, self.port, self.msi_conf)
> File ~/localfiles/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/msrestazure/azure_active_directory.py:548, in get_msi_token_webapp(resource, msi_conf)
> 546     raise RuntimeError(err_msg)
> 547 _LOGGER.debug('MSI: token retrieved')
> --> 548 token_entry = result.json()
> 549 return token_entry['token_type'], token_entry['access_token'], token_entry
> File ~/localfiles/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/models.py:975, in Response.json(self, **kwargs)
> 971     return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
> 972 except JSONDecodeError as e:
> 973     # Catch JSON-related errors and raise as requests.JSONDecodeError
> 974     # This aliases json.JSONDecodeError and simplejson.JSONDecodeError
> --> 975     raise RequestsJSONDecodeError(e.msg, e.doc, e.pos)
> JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

I do not want to use SDK2, it will break all my existing code.

I don't understand why the identidy is not automatically managed when starting the Compute Instances like Cluster Instances.

Does any one has a solution for this?

Comment: The real issue was that MSI on the computer instance were not correctly assigned. So the `MsiAuthentication` would not work at all since the compute instance would not have the var env associated to MSI

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code blocks to connect to the existing workspace using the python SDK using the compute instances.

- Create a compute instance

[image]

[image]

[image]

```
from azureml.core import Workspace
ws = Workspace.from_config()
ws.get_details()
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Connecting to workspace using Config file:**

```
import os
from azureml.core import Workspace

ws = Workspace.from_config()
```

[image]

Comment: This does not work for me:

`workspace = Workspace.from_config()`

> Performing interactive authentication. Please follow the instructions on the terminal.
WARNING:azureml._vendor.azure_cli_core.auth.identity:To sign in, use a web browser to open the page https://microsoft.com/devicelogin and enter the code XXXXXXX to authenticate.

Comment: I found a solution. I need to launch the Compute instance and then Authentificate it. For example I opened a Notebook, and the interface asked me to authentificate. And then I could use the python code. Isn't this possible to be automatic?